Python Flet single instance
Is it possible to create a single instance Flet web application? I would like to create a simple page just for my local network and run it on a raspberry controlling its GPIOs.
App image
Flet's default behavior is not to share state between different open pages, is it possible to change this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
